# Lektor CMS : Can't get lektor-tags to work properly, The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, tags, blogs, lektor, static-site-generation

I am trying to build a **blog** using `lektor CMS`, for that.. i needed a **tags system**, after searching i found a lektor plugin on lektor [docs](https://www.getlektor.com/plugins/lektor-tags/) called `lektor-tags`

I followed every step on the docs, struggled a lot and even visited the github [repo](https://github.com/lektor/lektor-tags) to see if is there anything else not included in the docs.

My problem is when i try to visit `localhost:5000/{the_tag_name}` say like `localhost:5000/python` i always get a `404 Not Found` saying that

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

This is what i did so far:

**Before** using `lektor-tags`:

1. I changed the route for the blog posts to be `/posts` instead of `/blog`.
2. Added slug format to `models/blog.ini` in `[children]`

   ```
    [children]
    model = blog-post
    order_by = pub_date, title
    slug_format = {{ (this.pub_date|dateformat('YYYY/M/') if this.pub_date) ~ this._id }}
   ```
3. Created 3 posts, **everything was working properly.**

**At this point** i wanted to use a tags system so i chosen to use `lektor-tags`, what i did was:

1. Installation

   ```
   lektor plugins add lektor-tags
   ```
2. Created `configs/tags.ini` with this config:

   ```
   parent = /
   url_path = {{ this.parent.url_path }}{{ tag }}
   tags_field = tags
   ignore_missing = true
   template = tags.html
   ```
3. Created `templates/tags.html` with the following content:

   ```
       {% extends "layout.html" %}
       {% block title %}{{ this.title }}{% endblock %}
       {% block body %}

       <div class="container mt-3">
           <b>Tag: {{ this.tag }}</b>
           <b>Items:</b>
           <ul>
                 {% for i in this.items %}
                 <li><a href="{{ i|url }}">{{ i._id }}</a></li>
                 {% else %}
                 <li><em>No items.</em></li>
                 {% endfor %}
           </ul>
       </div> 
       {% endblock %}
   ```
4. Edited `models/blog-post.ini` and added:

   ```
      [fields.tags]
      type = strings
   ```
5. In `templates/blog-post.html` i added the following to show links to the page that contain a list of all posts with the specific tag:

   ```
       {% if this.tags %}
       <ul>
            {% for t in this.tags -%}
            <li>
                 <a href="{{ ('/' ~ t.lower())|url }}">
                 All posts tagged {{ t }}
                 </a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
       </ul>
       {% endif %}
   ```
6. **Finally** i updated a post to contain some tags from the admin and made sure it's there in `content.lr` for that post. so i stopped the lektor dev server and run it again `lektor servor` with no errors to be present.

The links were there in the post for the tags but when i click and  follow a link say for example for the python tag `localhost:5000/python` i get `404 Not Found`. i am new to lektor. i'm wondering what i did wrong and how can i get this to work properly?

---

**NB:** Other plugins i used are `lektor-minify`, `lektor-disqus-comments` the docs for these plugins were straightforward and i didn't got confused, but when it comes to this specific plugin i were confused, struggling: the docs were not that great and explaining, i felt completely lost!

---

### **Update**

I created a [github repo](https://github.com/dzc0d3r/blog-lektor) containing the code and what i have done so far so you can easily replicate this.

---

### **Update 2**

I managed to get this to work properly see my answer below, however now i'm wondering how to set the root as the parent in other words how to edit this expression :

```
<a href="{{ ('/posts@tag/' ~ t.lower())|url }}">
```

to generate a source path for each of the blog post's tags but using root as the parent.
As you can see i tried this :

```
<a href="{{ ('/' ~ t.lower())|url }}">
```

but this doesn't work properly.

It's worth mentioning that lektor uses `jinja2` templating language.

Comment: you have to include the `@tag` part in your URL. Just use `/@tag/` instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Basically it was me doing this wrong because i wanted to use the root as the parent in `tags.ini` like so :

```
    parent = /
```

I ended up changing the expression `'/blog@tag/' ~ t.lower()` in `blog-post.html` to something like :

```
    <a href="{{ ('/' ~ t.lower())|url }}">
```

making it not able to generate a source path for each of the blog post's tags

**What i changed and worked was** :

1. I chosen `posts` to be the parent, updated the `configs/tags.ini` to :

   ```
   parent = /posts
   url_path = {{ this.parent.url_path }}{{ tag }}
   tags_field = tags
   ignore_missing = true
   template = tags.html
   ```
2. Updated `templates/blog-post.html` :

   ```
   {% if this.tags %}
   <ul>
       {% for t in this.tags -%}
       <li>
           # '/posts@tag/' ~ t.lower() because i changed the route of blog to posts
           <a href="{{ ('/posts@tag/' ~ t.lower())|url }}">
           All posts tagged {{ t }}
           </a>
       </li>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   {% endif %}
   ```

After running `lektor clean --yes` then `lekor server` everything was working properly including the tags system.